# Cannot attach the file *.mdf as database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mdf

I am trying to attach a `*.mdf` file to a SQL Server Express version. But I still have a problem with attach and then I removed a database and create a new but same problem when I use `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.

My default connection string is:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;AttachDBFilename=App_Data\\TVK3.mdf;Database=TVK3;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

I get this error:

> Cannot attach the file 'App_Data\TVK3.mdf' as database 'TVK3'.

I searching on google and trying some advice but nothing helped to me. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Are you able to attach when using an absolute filename?

Comment: Ouuu. Yea that's work. But i need relative not absolute path. Before i tried use %CONTENTROOTPATH% and replace that with env.ContentRootPath in startup (IHostingEnvironment env). But i had a problem because when app connecting everything is ok but when i tried Update-Database via console application dont run startup class what means CONTENTROOTPATH was not replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As davidbaumann said below my posts in comments. When i used absolute filename everythings working good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:
"AttachDBFilename=App_Data\TVK3.mdf;"

Comment: But i need attach exist database with data.